# Casing issues with git while creating branches

Tags: git

I have created a `bugfix/` branch using the command
`git checkout -b bugfix/bug-21`

When I try to push the branch it is giving error,
`fatal: Feature/Name cannot be resolved to branch`

But when i tried to push the same branch with upper case b it worked
`git checkout -b Bugfix/bug-21`

Though i want the branch with `bugfix/` not `Bugfix`

Comment: Invesitgate the issue by executing `git branch -a` - it will list all branches, including remotes - maybe you created remote branch with upperase?

Comment: What system are you pushing to? Is there already a remote branch with `Bugfix` in the name (`git branch --all`?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn no this is my first bugfix branch and I don't have another branch other than develop

Comment: @DaveShaw no, I don't another branch

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Please, post the command you are using to push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a head ref issue.Please follow the steps to make it work

`Step 1`

1. Open your code in `Explorer(windows) or Finder(mac)
   [image]
2. View hidden files(cmd + shift + . => mac,view -> show hidden files => windows)
   [image]
3. open .git > refs > heads >
   [image]
4. Now, you can see folder called `Bugfix`
5. Rename it to `bugfix`.Now try it will work

Also this is applicable for `release` and `feature` branches as well